# Stuck on an if... else function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn R for a class, and I'm stuck on how to create a simple If.. else.

The Excel file is a massive database, so I'm trying to simplify it below. (I'm not sure how to create columns in the ask function)

```
ID DOB      Type Date 
1  07/01/99 AA   01/20/2019
1  07/01/99 B    01/29/19
1  07/01/99 A    02/20/20
2  05/1/82  AA   07/12/15
2  05/1/82  B    08/19/17
2  05/1/82  D    08/19/19
3  05/1/82  AAA  06/17/15
3  05/1/82  A    07/19/2016
```

I'm trying to create a new column called "Time from visit" where:

- If the type matches "AA", then it's a "0"
- Otherwise, the date entry is subtracted from the type AA visit's date.
- For example, for ID = 1, Type = B, the value should be "10"

What can I try next?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Could you additionaly post your data in a format that allows us to run it on our system? That way we can recreate your situation and come up with the solution. Assuming your data frame is called `df` you can achieve that using `dput(df)` or if that's too large `dput(head(df))`. Furthermore, have you tried anything so far. It makes things easier to see the exact point where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `lubriate`:

You don't actually need an if/else statement because the date for `Type == "AA"` minus itself is 0.

Therefore, we just group the data by the `ID` and subtract the date for `Type == "AA"` from everything. The `[1]` helps return NA when there is no `AA` visit.

`lubridate::mdy` makes it easy to deal with the difference in year format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
         Time = Date - Date[Type == "AA"][1])
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID DOB      Type  Date       Time     
  <int> <fct>    <fct> <date>     <drtn>   
1     1 07/01/99 AA    2019-01-20    0 days
2     1 07/01/99 B     2019-01-29    9 days
3     1 07/01/99 A     2020-02-20  396 days
4     2 05/1/82  AA    2015-07-12    0 days
5     2 05/1/82  B     2017-08-19  769 days
6     2 05/1/82  D     2019-08-19 1499 days
7     3 05/1/82  AAA   2015-06-17   NA days
8     3 05/1/82  A     2016-07-19   NA days
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that function! That is really clear and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think if he/she is trying to learn the ifelse statement then it is important to make an example bacause me too when I was at the beginning of learning coding I did not understand things

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
test<- test %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date))
test$Timefromvisit<-ifelse(test$Type == "AA", 0, test$Date - lag(test$Date))
```

so basically by reusing the same code I take a dataframe "test" which contains your exemple excel file and I modified the format of the date and then I added the ifelse.
To explain the ifelse:
It takes 3 arguments specified inside the brackets.

```
1)test$Type == "AA" 
2) 0 
3) test$Date - lag(test$Date)
```

The fist argument is test$Type == "AA" which is your condition: if the "Type" column in the "test" dataframe is equal to AA, it adds a "0" which is specified in your second argument, otherwise if it is not, it does what you specify in your third argument which here is "test$Date - lag(test$Date)".
The third argument takes every date at each row in your Date column "test$Date" and substract by the previos value in the same column "lag(test$Date)"

Hope this explains

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to structure a personal function where if the type is one specific variable, it would be 0, anything else within the same ID group would be subtracted from that first group. This is helpful!